# Fig (Docker): how to specify which services to run depending on the environment

Tags: docker, fig

I'm using Fig (and Docker) to set up my dev environment.

One of the services that I have configured is [Adminer](http://www.adminer.org/), which is a lightweight web database client. I need it for development, but don't want it running in production. How can I do that? A solution for Fig (preferable) or Docker will do.

Here's a part of my `fig.yml`:

```
db:
  image: postgres
adminer:
  image: clue/adminer
  links:
    - db
  ports:
    - "8081:80"
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use multiple fig files. Fig uses fig.yml by default, but you can specify with the -f flag. [Docs](http://www.fig.sh/cli.html).

Thus, whatever you want your default to be could be fig.yml. Then, you could have fig-dev.yml (for example) for your development environment. Use fig -f fig-dev.yml up when using that one.

Comment: I like this, I'll take this one if there aren't any DRYer methods :).